# How can I reorder my divs using css for mobile view

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two different views.One for web version and other mobile version.
How can I get the view as shown in image below.
I can only get either of one.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="classAB">
      <div class="classA">
        <a>Home</a>
        <span>|</span>
        <a>Contact</a>
      </div>
      <div class="classB">
        <a>About</a>
        <span>|</span>
        <a>Address</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="classC">
      <p>
      qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.classAB {
   display: flex; 
   justify-content: space-between;
   text-align: center;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 531px) {
    .container { 
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center; 
    flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .classAB {
   display: flex; 
   justify-content: center;
   text-align: center;
   flex-direction: column;
}

.classA {
  order: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.classB {
  order: 3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.classC {
  order: 2;
}   
}
```

[image: screenshot of desired web view and mobile view]

If there is only one container and divs inside it. I know it would be simple.
But my issue is different.

Link to jsfiddle which contains my html and css is attached here:
[code which I have in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c6zqfv7e/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Delete `.classAB` and use something like this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.classC {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 531px){
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .classA {
    order: -2;
  }
  .classC {
    order: -1;
  }
  .classA,
  .classB {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .classA span,
  .classB span {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="classA">
    <a>Home</a>
    <span>|</span>
    <a>Contact</a>
  </div>
  <div class="classB">
    <a>About</a>
    <span>|</span>
    <a>Address</a>
  </div>
  <div class="classC">
    <p>qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty
  </div>
</div>
```